# Filling datagrid with async await method

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

my english is not very good sorry for that but i try to tell my problem perfectly

here is what i have for loading datagrid

```
private Task Loading(Func<string> SearchStringForUser)
{

    return Task.Run(() =>
    {

        var query = database.Database.SqlQuery<VW_Users>("select * From VW_Users where 1 = 1 And GymID = " + PublicVar.ID + " " + SearchStringForUser());
        var user = query.ToList();
        Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            DataGrid_User.ItemsSource = user;
        });
    });
}
```

first things first i have a InvokeAsync But it not work perfectly i mean my program getting hang when loaded data is going to list.
Anyway , its not my main problem but if someone knows what is that reason can point to it
 but my main problem is when i have +200 row . program dont load all of dates for 30 secends or more . looks like my program datagrid is empty for 30secends or more.

i want to load datas by 10 rows 10 rows , i mean i want to fill my datagrid when 10 rows loaded, after next 10 rows,
like
10
20
30
40
....
with this my datagrid will never empty
and data will loaded slowly 
can someone tell me the best way to do that?

Comment: You don't need to use the Dispatcher. Just move the ItemsSource assignment out of the Task. Do it after awaiting the query Task. Declare the Loading method async.

Comment: Anyway it dont will be work cuz i gett error : the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it async
but if i move ItemsSource out of the task it will be working async? is that possble?

Comment: and one more qustion , if it dont work like Async why its called InvokeAsync? And there is diffrent beetwen Anvoke and InvokeAsync?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call the database on a background thread but set the `ItemsSource` property on the UI thread. So your `Task` should return an `IEnumerable<User>` but don't touch the `DataGrid`. You can then await the `Task`.

This should work provides that the `Loading` method is called from the UI thread:

```
private async Task Loading(Func<string> SearchStringForUser)
{
    var user = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var query = database.Database.SqlQuery<VW_Users>("select * From VW_Users where 1 = 1 And GymID = " + PublicVar.ID + " " + SearchStringForUser());
        return query.ToList();
    });
    DataGrid_User.ItemsSource = user;
}
```

But since query returns all rows at once, there is no "when 10 rows are loaded". You get them all at once. If you don't want this you need to use some kind of a data reader to read records one by one. You could create an `ObservableCollection` and populate this one in intervals. Here is an example that should give you the idea:

```
ObservableCollection<VW_Users> collection = new ObservableCollection<VW_Users>();
object @lock = new object();
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(collection, @lock);
DataGrid_User.ItemsSource = collection;

Task.Run(() =>
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connection string...."))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * From VW_Users where GymID = @GymId", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("GymId", PublicVar.ID + " " + SearchStringForUser());
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            const int N = 10;
            VW_Users[] cache = new VW_Users[N];
            int counter = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                VW_Users obj = new VW_Users();
                obj.Property1 = Convert.ToString(reader["Column1"]);
                cache[counter] = obj;
                //...and so on for each property...

                if (++counter == N)
                {
                    //add N items to the source collection
                    foreach (VW_Users x in cache) collection.Add(x);
                    counter = 0;
                    //add a delay so you actually have a chance to see that N items are added at a time
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            //add any remaining items
            for (int i = 0; i<counter; ++i) collection.Add(cache[i]);
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
});
```

Comment: thank u so much , it solved my side 
Question , can u check the my main 
Question?

Comment: @RezaPak: Your query returns all rows at once, doesn't it? So there is no "when 10 rows are loaded". You get them all at once. If you don't want this you need to ditch Entity Framework or whatever ORM you are using and use some kind of a data reader.

Comment: You mean how to use a data reader? There is an example of MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: Thank u for Your Helping, i got it , but for last qustion what i should write in while (reader.Read())
            {
        this line
            } to load data and my datagrid no empty when it start

Comment: @RezaPak: You need to create VW_Users object that you then add to a list that you then assign the ItemsSource property to.

Comment: im new on this one, can u edit your code and write what i should do? with code. becuz its my main problem aculy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183117/discussion-between-reza-pak-and-mm8).

Comment: Thank You So Much , every answer is true. i know i hit u with this little quiston ... i  have one more qustion ... if i have a Progress bar called "progressload" how i can config it to loading data , when dates load its going to 100% . can u help me ? if u dont no problem i know u might be tired

Comment: @RezaPak: Please ask another question if you have another issue. If you post the link to it here I will try to help you. Please remember to include all relevant code snippets and details in the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53171280/loading-data-in-datagrid-match-by-progress-bar
can u check that?