# Loading data in datagrid match by Progress bar

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Here is what i have so far :

```
        #region Method For Loading Data
    private async Task Loading(Func<string> SearchStringForUser)
    {
        ObservableCollection<VW_Users> collection = new ObservableCollection<VW_Users>();
        object @lock = new object();
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(collection, @lock);
        DataGrid_User.ItemsSource = collection;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {


            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(PublicVar.ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * From VW_Users where 1 = 1 And @GymID = @GymId", connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GymID", PublicVar.GymID + " " + SearchStringForUser());
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    const int N = 10;
                    VW_Users[] cache = new VW_Users[N];
                    int counter = 0;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        VW_Users obj = new VW_Users();
                        obj.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserID"]);
                        obj.UserName = Convert.ToString(reader["UserName"]);            
                        cache[counter] = obj;
                        //...and so on for each property...

                        if (++counter == N)
                        {
                            //add N items to the source collection
                            foreach (VW_Users x in cache)
                            {
                                collection.Add(x);


                            } 
                            counter = 0;
                            this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => {
                                MyProg.Value += 20;
                            });

                            ////add a delay so you actually have a chance to see that N items are added at a time
                               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                        }
                    }
                    //add any remaining items
                    for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
                    {
                        collection.Add(cache[i]);

                    }

                }
                reader.Close();
            }

        });

    }
    #endregion
```

its awaiting for load data into my datagrid , now i have two qustion right here 
how i can make a image rotated 360 like loading image...
and my important qustion is how i can show the loaded data by Progress bar
like when 10% of datas loaded my Progress bar value get 10% when it done my Progress bar get 100% . i callled my Progress bar "MyProg" in my codes, but it dont work nicey. what is best idea for do that?

Comment: See [using datareader async](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adonet/2012/07/15/using-sqldatareaders-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5-part-2-examples/).

Comment: Avoid Task.Run() and Sleep(). You don't need them and they bite you here.

Comment: You don't know how many rows your query will return until you have read them so there is no way to know that you have processed 10% given your current implementation.

Comment: can u help me about rotaded 360*  a image ? like loding images animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how i can show the loaded data by Progress bar like when 10% of datas loaded my Progress bar value get 10% when it done my Progress bar get 100% ?

You don't know how many rows your query will return until you have read them so there is no way to know that you have processed 10% given your current implementation. You may want to use a `ProgressBar` with the `IsIndeterminate` property set to `true` though.

As @bommelding pointed out, you may also want to consider using the asynchronous API of the `SqlDataReader` class instead of using `Task.Run`: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adonet/2012/07/15/using-sqldatareaders-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5-part-2-examples/

> how i can make a image rotated 360 like loading image ?

Given an `Image` element that you have added to your XAML markup like this:

```
<Image x:Name="image" Source="image.png" />
```

..you can set its `LayoutTransform` or `RenderTransform` property to a `RotateTransform` that you animate like this:

```
RotateTransform rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
image.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
image.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty,
    new DoubleAnimation() { From = 0, To = 360, Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever, FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop });

await Task.Run(...);

rotateTransform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, null);
```

Comment: everything is ok expect it move 
in its place , i just want to rotated 360

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Did you try to set the `RenderTransform` instead of `LayoutTransform`?

Comment: i copy pasted all of your codes in my source, my image is rotated 360 its ok . but image is moving to right side and back , i just want to rotaded 360 not moving

Comment: @RezaPak: Use `RenderTransform` and set the `RenderTransformOrigin` property of the `Image` to `0.5,0.5`.

Comment: @RezaPak: I just did.

Comment: Thnx u , but it still moving. i change my image and test with some other images . all of them are moving yet

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "moving". The image is being animated. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: I just wanna Rotate my image in fix  place  It happens i can see 

 . But my image goes to the left and right when its rotate

Comment: I mean that the rotation is right, but not in the fixed location

Comment: I want to rotate exactly in fixed place

Comment: My example rotate the image around its center. You can change the values if you don't want this.

Comment: u know my mean? if u know can u update your post? or not im try solo to fix that . thanks for all of your help

Comment: u helped me so much