# c# wpf Filling datagrid with async await method

Tags: wpf

[Filling datagrid with async await method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53151080/filling-datagrid-with-async-await-method)

I would like to use the function in the above link.

```
using MySqlConnection con = new(Common.JOIN);
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new(
                        $"SELECT * FROM item WHERE CONCAT (`i_type`) like '{type.Text}' ORDER BY `i_name` ASC;", con);
                    MySqlDataAdapter adp = new(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new();
                    adp.Fill(ds, "LoadDataBinding");
                    datagrid.DataContext = ds;
```

The tone may be a little odd.
I ask a question through Google Translate.

The code I am using is as above.

To use the code I use from the link in the link
How do I fix it?

I'm using C# WPF.

Comment: I would like to know whether to load data one by one asynchronously, or both at once, but I would be really happy if only one of them works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would replace this line

```
datagrid.DataContext = ds;
```

With this one

```
datagrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["LoadDataBinding"].DefaultView;
```

Then it should work